# Mimic Apple's fingerprint setting flow in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, ios-animations, android-fingerprint-api

I am wondering how Apple implemented the growing fingerprint effect in the fingerprint setting flow. Is it possible in Android? I think it looks like some kind of progress bar in Android, but I am curious about how it works and how it actually relates with the fingerprint api in Android 6.0